# Optimization with an inherent differential equation

Tags: matlab, optimization, differential-equations

I am trying to solve an optimization problem where the given objective function is to minimize

```
norm(R - R*)
```

where `R` is obtained by solving a boundary value problem (BVP) and `R* is a known value.

For example:

```
R = (p1 + p2*p3);
```

The BVP is given by

```
p1dot = p2 + p3 + x1;
p2dot = x2 + p1*p2;
p3dot = x3 + p1*p2*p3;
```

where `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are the optimized variables.

I am trying to solve this in MATLAB using `fmincon` where the BVP is solved in  the objective function at every guess by the solver to estimate `norm(R-R*)`.

**EDIT 1** : I have a non linear inequality constraint which is a function of `pi` where `i = 1,2,3`. This is the reason for choosing `fmincon`

The issue I am facing is that during some guesses the BVP doesn't converge and the optimization stops. I guess the issue is some guess value to solve the BVP doesn't satisfy. If I give bounds to the variables then it solves the optimization problem. I am not really aware of the bounds on variables beforehand.

In order to overcome this I want to detect the guess when BVP is not solved, save them and force the optimization routine to not try values when it cannot be solved by going back to its previous guess. How do we implement this in `fmincon` routine?

**EDIT 2 :** I figured out the issue is with initial guess provided to the `BVP solver`. For smaller values of the optimization variables `x` this guess is good but when the magnitude of `x` increase this guess is not good enough.

Is there a way to update the solution of 'BVP' in the previous iteration as the initial guess for the next iteration in optimization. Intuitively this should fix it. Please let me know if there are some loop holes in this method.

Comment: Why do you use `fmincon` if you don't have/know any constraints? You could use `fminunc` or `fminsearch`.

Comment: Personally I think that a better solution to your problem is to first select as algorithm interior-point, and then let your objective function return NaN when the BVP doesn’t converge. Adding bounds, even large ones, however will help a lot fmincon.

Comment: Better put: *diverges* (because limiting the number of iterations etc. might be biasing the outcomes)

Comment: Or penalize the solution (instead of plain NaN) to better direct the optimization

Comment: Sorry. I have a nonlinear constraint which I didn't mention in the question, that is why I am using `fmincon`. I will add it to the question

Comment: @Jommy Can you elaborate? How can I force Objective function to return NaN when BVP diverges?

Comment: A possible choice is inserting if `~all(isfinite(bvpSolution)), costFun=NaN; return; end`, but you might also introduce a threshold to determine if the BVP has diverged.

Comment: @Jommy I figured out the reason for divergence (EDIT 2) in the question

Comment: This kind of task is solved by employing a `global` variable, and update it by means of an output function https://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html. Anyhow I still think that adding bounds to the optimization variable is way easier.

Comment: @Jommy I am using global currently. May be I should post a new question. I cannot do parallel computation when I use global which leads to large computational time. So essentially looking for a method which can use parallel and updated initial guess.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, and I'm not aware of a way to accomplish this task in a neat way.